# Change the JSON structure response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, return, return-value

I created the json response for the item using this code:

```
this.parts = this.getParts().filter((item) => {
  return item.manufactureId === Number(manufactureId)
  });
```

it's return the ID of part from my this json:

```
[{id: 02020013, manufactureId: 0202, name: cable}]
```

I also tried using this code but not working :(":

```
this.parts = this.getParts.filter(p => (p.id == manufactureId))[0].name;
```

What I want to achieved is, the response will parse the item name instead of part.id.

Comment: You need to call getParts to get the data and filter that, rather than filtering the function

Comment: Hi @jro, can you please give the example? or in more details? thanks in adavance

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @MantasČekanauskas, currently my script will give the response part id number (02020013) only, what I want to do is the response will only give the part name value

Comment: It appears the mistake pointed out in my comment and in an answer are just a typo in the code. Please update your question to reflect your actual attempted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in comments you can change you last code bit to

```
this.parts = this.getParts().filter(p => (p.manufactureId == manufactureId))[0].name;
```

You were missing parenthesis to call a function. And you might need to filter by `manufactureId`, not `id`.

As well you can use `map` function after filtering data by `manufactureId`.  `map` function applies function for each array element and return result, in this example it simple get `name` from object, because there might be more that one (or none) item by `manufactureId`.

```
this.parts = this.getParts().filter((item) => {
    return item.manufactureId === Number(manufactureId)
}).map((item) => item.name);
```